# Pass value to a NestJS service

Tags: typescript, dependency-injection, nestjs

In my NestJS app, I have a service that is used for performing HTTP requests with a vendor (acting as a client library for that vendor). The service needs an API key, which is available as an env var `VENDOR_API_KEY`.

For unit tests, I want to use another, hardcoded value for the API key - instead of taking it from `VENDOR_API_KEY`.

What is the idiomatic way of doing it? All of the options given in https://docs.nestjs.com/fundamentals/custom-providers seem like overkill.

I might be missing something obvious because I'm new to NestJS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you'd need a very simple custom provider. Something as quick as

```js
@Module({
  providers: [
    ServiceToBeUsed,
    {
      provide: 'API_KEY',
      useValue: process.env.VENDOR_API_KEY, //you could also use a factory and inject the config service
    }
  ]
})
export class SomeModule {}
```

And now you can use `@Inject('API_KEY') private readonly apiKey: string` in your service's constructor

Comment: This is great, and I tweaked it a little: on normal (not unit-testing) operation, I want it to use `process.env.VENDOR_API_KEY` without the overhead in `providers`. So I added `@Optional()` just before `@Inject`, and put `process.env.VENDOR_API_KEY` as the default value.